# Possible to set CSS font-size as a relative % of what the class is defined with using style property?

Tags: html, css, fonts

What I have is a div class="myBox" and "myTitle"

the CSS for **`.myBox`**:

```
{
font-size:14px
}
```

the CSS for **`.myTitle`**:

```
{
font-size:18px
}
```

Now in certain scenarios I want these both to scale up or down by a percentage.  So I setup a **`style="font-size:150%"`** and I simply add that to my HTML

This successfully overrides the CSS class and applies a 150% font size to the classes.

---

### The Problem

Both .myBox and .myTitle are now equally large, they aren't maintaining a relative difference in font size.  It seems the 150% is in regards to a global font-size for the page so when I tell it to goto 150% they are the same.

What I was hoping was for:

```
.myBox would be 150% * 14px = 21px
.myTitle would be 150% * 18px = 27px
```

Is there a way I can set the font size to scale as a percentage up using only CSS and the style property?

Comment: Take a look at `em` https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a job for `em`. `em` is a relative unit that is based on the parent's font size. Search about it and you'll find plenty of resources, including it's partner in crime, the `rem` unit (`:root` `em`) https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/css2em.htm

```css
body {
  line-height: 1;
}

.box {
  font-size: 14px
}

.title {
  font-size: 18px
}

.bigger {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">box (14px)
  <div class="myBox bigger">mybox (21px)</div>
</div>

<div class="title">box (18px)
  <div class="myTitle bigger">mybox (27px)</div>
</div>
```